# How do I copy scrollable text output in iterm2 with tmux?

Tags: copy, mouse, tmux, iterm2

I'm using tmux on iterm2 (3.0.12). I can generally copy text by holding the 'Option (alt)' key and dragging with mouse.

But, this doesn't work when I need to select and copy text output that is bigger than my window/pane size. That is the text for which I need to scroll to view it. e.g. 500 lines of text log.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a simple way to do this using the mouse.
For selection inside the windows/pane you can use the mouse with Option (Alt) modifier. I'm using this setup:

```
# Handling mouse
set -g mouse on
# Fix Mouse Scrolling: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/145
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t=; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
bind -n WheelDownPane select-pane -t= \; send-keys -M
```

With this settings you can select using the mouse and the Option (alt) key and then use Cmd-C to copy the selection inside the current window/pane.
However, if you try to scroll outside of the window/pane, the whole page scroll, not the content.

To be able to select and copy a bigger chunk of text you can use the copy mode.

In this case I've followed [this post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tmux-copy-paste-on-os-x-a-better-future) and it works.

edit: initial answer was incomplete